# Получить куки для использования в функции C#

Tags: c#, сервер, авторизация

Использую webbrowser для авторизации на сайте. Но на win 10 он почему-то просто обновляет страницу, а авторизация не происходит. На win 7 все нормально. Решил сразу при загрузке формы привязывать куки с помощью функции InternetSetCookie. 
Но просто руками вбить ключи и значения куки не вариант, они там меняются, похоже. Поэтому вопрос: как можно получить куки с сайта film4smart.net и записать их в функцию InternetSetCookie?
На данный моммент делаю так:

```
string url = "http://film4smart.net/load/0-0-0-0-1";
InternetSetCookie(url, "0filmcorpsocses", "BLNFuKhrCWiqtamdys6Qy7Ne2Uxhm9JjFaV%5E6LNRNxmLHwoo;");
InternetSetCookie(url, "0filmcorpuispm", "1475931860-0;");
InternetSetCookie(url, "body-class", "st-cyan;");
InternetSetCookie(url, "0filmcorpuzll", "1476100531;");
InternetSetCookie(url, "0filmcorpuCoz", "1QCeH1b4ktFG0Zt;");
InternetSetCookie(url, "0filmcorppPp", "0;");
InternetSetCookie(url, "0filmcorpp2", "0;");
InternetSetCookie(url, "0filmcorppSum", "0;");
InternetSetCookie(url, "0filmcorppA16", "0;");
webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
```

Но так оно не работает, т.к., как я уже и говорил, куки постоянно меняются. Т.е. я какой-то период был авторизован, но прошла пара часов, и все куки поменялись.

Еще пробовал менять режим работы webbrowser на ie 11, но это не помогло... Если знаете другой способ как можно авторизоваться, буду очень благодарен за него.

Answer (score -1):

Можно через HttpWebRequest тогда у вас будет полный контроль над запросами, но если нужен браузер попробуте Selenium там есть Edge и Chrome

Comment: А минус за что?

Comment: Минус не мой, но возможно причина в том, что это скорее не ответ, а просто намёк на путь решения. И намёк, на мой взгляд, хороший, верный. Но самого решения-то нет )